# What is the most efficient way to include an API on a page?

Tags: php, api, class

The website I am re-building uses its own API to gather most of its content (e.g. http://api.example.com/). Although the answer to this is quite self explanatory, I just want to be sure before I proceed.

As far as I am aware, I have 2 (potentially 3) options of loading the data from the api via PHP.

1. I can load the classes into the document and gather the data manually from the class (probably the best way, but requires more code and if changes are made to the class, I have to alter the pages and the API document instead of just changing the API)
2. Use `file_get_contents('http://api.example.com/search')`. This would be the easiest way but it requires another HTTP request and I assume it is slightly slower.
3. **Lastly, if this this possible then I think it will be the best way, but to my knowledge I do not think it is possible. Read the file locally with `$_GET` parameters implemented and obtain the results this way.**

**EXAMPLES**

1.

```
// Include the mysql connections
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/scripts/php/_connections/mysql.company.php');

// Include the Classes (Company and Facebook)
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/scripts/php/_classes/class.company.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/scripts/php/_classes/class.mysql.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/scripts/php/_facebook/config.facebook.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/scripts/php/_facebook/class.facebook.php');

// Create the objects (Company, MySQL, Memcache and Facebook)
$memcache = new memcache;
$facebook = new Facebook($facebook_config);
$mysql = new mysql($memcache);
$company = new company($_DATABASES,$_CONNECTIONS,$mysql,$memache,$facebook);

// CALL THE RELEVANT CLASS METHOD HERE
```

2.
Something like (ignore mistakes)

```
$API = 'http://api.example.com/search?query=test'
$data = file_get_contents(url_encode($API));
```

3.
Not sure if this is possible, please note I do NOT want to use the last method

```
$parameters = array(
    'method'=>'GET',
    'parameters'=>array(
        'function'=>'search',
        'query'=>'test'
    )
);
$API = some_cool_function('/_scripts/api/2/api/api.php',$parameters);

// I DO NOT WANT TO DO THIS FOR CERTAIN REASONS:
$_GET=array(
    'function'=>'search',
    'query'=>'test'
);
$data = include('/_scripts/api/2/api/api.php');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally I'd say the 1st option - with Oauth etc that's in place in most API's these days I'm sure a nicely wrapped class setup would be much easier to work with.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Is the third option not possible then?

Comment: I guess it would depend on what's in api.php - but just manually filling the $_GET isn't great practice alone. Methods 2 and 3 look simple and great, but in reality they would probably age badly and cause you no end of problems down the line. With a class that can be simply updated you would hardly ever need to change your method calls etc. Plus you'd be sticking everything into $data - if it's not an object that's a strange thing to be doing really.

Comment: api.php simply returns a JSON encoded string resulting from the API function, that is why $data is given the result. I couldn't agree more that setting $_GET parameters and then including a file is bad practice, it is terrible practice!!